# How to get alert response from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, response

I want to get response from php which I have echoed and display using alert in js.

My js is as follows:

```
$('input#Upload').on('click',function(){
    var table_name = $('select#Select').val();
    $.post('Manip_ValueToDB.php',{table_name: table_name}, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

My php is as follows:

```
<?php

if($_POST['table_name']){
    echo "Response";
}

?>
```

Comment: What's not working as expected? (**ok**) Any errors in your JavaScript console (F12) ? (**ok**) If you put an `alert('test');` after the line `var table_name..`, does it get executed?

Comment: I don't get an alert for this code. I tried clearing my cache and browser history but non worked.

Comment: No error in console as well.

Comment: Yes, I do get an alert when I put an alert('test'); after the line var table_name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap everything in document.ready and also check for syntax errors. Also, dont forget to include jquery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('input#Upload').on('click',function(){
        var table_name = $('select#Select').val();
        $.post('Manip_ValueToDB.php',{table_name: table_name}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Check if table_name is not empty. `alert(table_name)`.... also check your browser console for js errors

Comment: Yes, I did that, its not empty. My browser console shows no js errors. It is just not showing the alert box. I tried it in every possible browser I have, it is not working. :(

Comment: Is jquery included ? And what version are you using ?

Comment: Yes, it is included. It's 1.8.0.

Comment: Also, try console.log(data) instead of alert and check in browser console

Comment: I am wondering why **function(data){alert(data);}** is not working? I did console.log(data) but, console is showing nothing. :(

Comment: ok, I think there is no data coming from your ajax request. Did you check your ajax request. It is in net tab (in developer console) if you are using firefox and in network tab (in developer console) if you are using chrome. So, check these two things, 1. is there any request happening ? 2. response of your ajax request

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't get a response. What should I do for that?

Comment: that means your PHP code failing, try simple `echo test` instead of your "if" condition. If that works that means your PHP check is failing. After that you can try `print_r($_POST)` to check what data is coming inside post global vars

Comment: You mean, you tried simple `echo test` on your php file and its not working ?
did you remove everything in your php file and just put `<?php echo "test"; ?>`

Comment: are you sure your PHP is working ? try running same file in browser i.e [http://localhost/yourfile.php](http://localhost/yourfile.php) it should print test on browser

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have a syntax error in your JS.

```
$('input#Upload').on('click',function(){

 var table_name = $('select#Select').val();

    $.post('Manip_ValueToDB.php',{table_name: table_name}, function(data) {

    alert(data);

    });

});
```

You were missing a closing ) around the data parameter in the call back of your AJAX call.

Comment: I am sorry for that but, I knew that. Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the issue now? Do you get any errors in the console? Can you access the php script in the browser?

Comment: Put a console log at the top of your callback function for the click. I have a feeling your click function isn't being called.

Comment: The issue is that I don't get alert box for the response. I have tried everything that I know. I tried clearing the history and cache, i tried console.log(data) but, the console shows nothing.

Comment: Yeah, it is being called. Just the anonymous function is not working and I don't know why?

Comment: Try adding an error callback as well - AJAX might not be able to find the script and the success callback would never run

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a '('

example

```
$('input#Upload').on('click', function() {

  var table_name = $('select#Select').val();

  $.post('Manip_ValueToDB.php', {
    table_name: table_name
  }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ua27Uv5X60A1VnW5aSu?p=info

Comment: ? Your code is exactly the same as the one from the question.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake, my bad. :(

Comment: ir works ? , if you put in the console $('input#Upload') and $('select#Select') you get the reference ?